# Will ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blah"] throw an exception if "blah" doesn't exist?

Tags: .net, configuration

Will ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blah"] throw an exception if "blah" doesn't exist in the web/app.config?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

No, it returns `null`.

Answer (score 26):

From the [MSDN documentation for NameValueCollection.Item Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx):

> **Caution**
>
> This property returns null in the following cases: 1) if the specified key is not found; and 2) if the specified key is found and its associated value is null. This property does not distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 8):

No, it returns `null`.

AppSettings is a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) - as per the [caution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8e7f4s6.aspx) on the [NameValueCollection.Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8e7f4s6.aspx) page:

> This method returns a null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic) in the
>   following cases: 1) if the specified
>   key is not found; and 2) if the
>   specified key is found and its
>   associated value is a null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic). This method
>   does not distinguish between the two
>   cases.

Answer (score 6):

No, it returns `null`.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection` - from [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx):

> The Get method does not distinguish
>   between **null which is returned because
>   the specified key is not found** and
>   null which is returned because the
>   value associated with the key is null.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 4):

Other answers reference the documentation for the Item property. It might not be immediately obvious why they are relevant looking at the following code snippet.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blah"]
```

The square bracket syntax is used in C# to access indexers. These are special properties that allow a class to be indexed in the same way that an array can be. Looking at the definition of the [NameValueCollection.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) property, you will notice that it does not use the normal property syntax. The this keyword and the indexer parameters are used to define this property as an indexer.

```
public string this[
    string name
] { get; set; }
```

In the documentation, indexers are implicitly named Item and parameters are surrounded by square brackets.

[image: Indexers as shown in the MSDN documentation.]

It is not clear to me why there were answers that referenced the [Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8e7f4s6(v=vs.110).aspx) method - maybe one calls the other?

At any rate, to answer the question...

**No. An exception will not be thrown if you access a non-existent key - a null will be returned.**

Here is the relevant section from the [NameValueCollection.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb(v=vs.110).aspx) property documentation.

> This property returns null in the following cases: 1) if the specified
>   key is not found; and 2) if the specified key is found and its
>   associated value is null. This property does not distinguish between
>   the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said, it will just return null.

However, if you want it to throw an exception when not found one could do this:

```
var myImportantSetting= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["important_setting"] ?? throw new SettingsPropertyNotFoundException("AppSetting missing.");
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Edit: this is clearly wrong. Left for the helpful comments below.

Comment: the answer to your question is No like @Tim mentioned. The page pointed to just said that if appsettings are not able to be loaded then an exception is thrown. But if a value is just not present in the appsettings then you will not get an exception. It really wouldn't make sense to throw an error just because a value doesn't exist in a dictionary. But if the dictionary didn't exist then that would be a reason to throw an error. (The term dictionary was just used to refer to an arbitrary collection.)

Comment: That link says that an exception is thrown if the `NameValueCollection` could not be found - i.e. the system could not find *any* settings.  Name Value Collections do not thrown an exception when you try to retrieve a single value that does not exist..